# How do I create objects and add them to a list with a button click event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UI which allows the user to create custom objects of class "Bird" by entering name and attributes. I need a button to add the newly created Birds to a "List of Birds". How should my code look like?

The class Bird has a subclass "Nest". Birds can have multiple Nests, hence there's a List of Nests.

I currently have this code, which doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NewBird
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
        public MainWindow()
 {

    }

    List<Bird> BirdList = new List<Bird>();
    Bird bx = new Bird();
    List<Bird.Nest> NList = new List<Bird.Nest>();

    private void AddNewBird_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process tempBird = new Process();     
        string tempName = birdtextbox.Text;
    }


    private void AddNewNest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bird.Nest tempNest = new Bird.Nest();
        NList.Add(tempNest);
    }

    private void Add2List_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bird holder = new Bird();
        holder= bx;
        holder.nl = NList;
        BirdList.Add(holder);
        }
    }
}    



public class Bird
    {
        public string BirdName { get; set; }
        public List<Nest> nl { get; set; }
        public Nest nest{ get; set; }
    [Serializable()]
        public class Nest
        {
            public int Number { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

"Add2List_Click" overwrites the previous Bird instead of adding a new one to the BirdList.

Comment: I suppose that this line _holder= bx;_ is your problem. Add the variable _holder_ instead.

Comment: You mean I should eliminate the bx step and use only holder instead?

Comment: Or remove the creation of a new Bird and use _bx_ then create a new instance of a Bird and assign it to _bx_ Also the global for the Nest list is not needed, you have already one inside an instance of a Bird (so you can add to bx.nl )

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your current code does:

```cs
private void Add2List_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new Bird and put it in `holder` variable, so far so good.
    Bird holder = new Bird();

    // Replace the content of `holder` (our new Bird) with an existing Bird!
    // The line `Bird holder = new Bird()` just above became pointless since you never use your new Bird.
    // bx is the Bird that was created earlier in your `MainWindow`.
    holder= bx;
    holder.nl = NList;

    // Now you're adding `holder` to the list, but `holder` is not the new Bird anymore, it's the old one.
    BirdList.Add(holder);
    }
}
```

What you probably want to do is the following:

```cs
private void Add2List_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new Bird and put it in `holder` variable.
    Bird holder = new Bird();

    // Create a new List with two new Nests for our new Bird...
    holder.nl = new List<Bird.Nest> { new Nest(), new Nest() };
    // ...or use the existing list of Nests with this line:
    // holder.nl = NList;

    // Add the new Bird to the list.
    BirdList.Add(holder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now the list of Nests keeps adding all Nests to each Bird. I tried to define 2 Nests for two Birds each, but now both Birds have four Nests.

Comment: It feels like this should be another question. Anyway I edited my code to create two new nests for each bird. What you should understand is that if you use the same list for two birds, then adding a nest to the first bird will add it to the second bird as well, as they share the list! Either create a list with two nests and set this list for each new bird, or create a new list with two nests for each new bird.